# Dagger2 error: [Dagger/MissingBinding] com.testtask.hotels.data.IRepository cannot be provided without an @Provides-annotated method

Tags: android, dagger-2, dagger, dagger-hilt

I'm studying Dagger2 and I've got an error: `error: [Dagger/MissingBinding] com.testtask.hotels.data.IRepository cannot be provided without an @Provides-annotated method.`

**RepositoryModule**

```
@Module(includes = [NetworkModule::class])
@DisableInstallInCheck
abstract class RepositoryModule {

    @Singleton
    @Binds
    abstract fun provideRepository(repository: RepositoryImpl): IRepository
}
```

**RepositoryImpl**

```
class RepositoryImpl @Inject constructor(
    private val api: ApiService,
) : IRepository {

    override suspend fun getHotels(): List<BaseHotelInfo> {
        return api.getHotels()
    }

    override suspend fun getConcreteHotelInfo(hotelId: Int): FullHotelInfo {
        return api.getConcreteHotel(hotelId)
    }
}
```

**AppComponent**

```
@Component(modules = [RepositoryModule::class])
@Singleton
interface AppComponent {

    fun inject(app: App)
    fun inject(hotelsFragment: AllHotelsFragment)
    fun inject(rootActivity: RootActivity)
}
```

**RootActivity**

```
@AndroidEntryPoint
class RootActivity : BaseActivity<RootViewModel>() {

    companion object {
        private const val TAG = "M_RootActivity"
    }

    override val layout: Int = R.layout.activity_root

    override val viewModel: RootViewModel by viewModels()

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    }
}
```

**RootViewModel**

```
@HiltViewModel
class RootViewModel @Inject constructor(
    val repository: IRepository
): BaseViewModel() {

}
```

I've checked guides for @Binds and I didn't see any differences to my
What could be the reason?

Comment: Have you tried replacing the `@Binds` annotation on your repository in your `NetworkModule` with `@Provides`?

Comment: I was mixing Dagger2 with Hilt, that was wrong way.

Comment: You are using way too old tutorials for Dagger. Things like: fun inject(rootActivity: RootActivity) date like 3 years back.